How can I use filter function in Excel to filter based on selections including those that are "ALL"?
I would like to use filter function so that when various selections are made, it filters the data accordingly even if sometimes the selection is "All" or just left blank.

I can do this for one selection using:
=FILTER(A7:A10,A7:A10=b2,A7:A10)

but doesn't seem to work when I was to use multiple selections:
=FILTER(A7:A10,(A7:A10=b2,A7:A10)*(B7:B10=b3,B7:B10))

or
=FILTER(A7:A10,(A7:A10=b2)*(B7:B10=b3),A7:A10)


Show All Data If Filter Criteria Are "All" or Blank
=LET(data,A7:B10,crit,B2:B3,
    OneOrFilter,LAMBDA(array,crit,IF(OR(crit="All",crit=""),1,array=crit)),
    nf,OneOrFilter(CHOOSECOLS(data,1),INDEX(crit,1)),
    lf,OneOrFilter(CHOOSECOLS(data,2),INDEX(crit,2)),
    IF(AND(nf=1,lf=1),data,FILTER(data,nf*lf,"")))

i.e.
=LET(
    OneOrFilter,LAMBDA(array,crit,IF(OR(crit="All",crit=""),1,array=crit)),
    nf,OneOrFilter(A7:A10,B2),
    lf,OneOrFilter(B7:B10,B3),
    IF(AND(nf=1,lf=1),A7:B10,FILTER(A7:B10,nf*lf,"")))


The OneOrFilter function returns either 1, if the criteria is "All" or blank, or an array of TRUE/FALSEs, as the result of comparing a column against a criterion.
In the final statement, check if the results for all columns (there could be more than 2) are 1 when the requirement is to show all data. Otherwise, show the filtered data.


include_all, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data), , 1, 0) = 1 (TRUE) for all rows.
=LAMBDA(data, crit_1, crit_2,
    LET(
        include_all, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data), , 1, 0),
        all_or_crit, LAMBDA(col_num, crit,
            IF(
                OR(LEN(TRIM(crit)) = 0, TRIM(crit) = "ALL"),
                include_all,
                INDEX(data, , col_num) = crit
            )
        ),
        FILTER(
            data,
            all_or_crit(1, crit_1) *
                all_or_crit(2, crit_2)
        )
    )
)(A7:B10, B2, B3)


Partial match
Option for partial match (case insensitive with SEARCH) by entering criteria text with *:
=LAMBDA(data, crit_1, crit_2,
    LET(
        include_all, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data), , 1, 0),
        all_or_crit, LAMBDA(col_num, crit,
            IFS(
                OR(
                    LEN(TRIM(crit)) = 0,
                    TRIM(crit) = "ALL"
                ),
                include_all,
                ISNUMBER(SEARCH("~*", crit)),
                ISNUMBER(
                    SEARCH(crit, INDEX(data, , col_num))
                ),
                TRUE,
                INDEX(data, , col_num) = crit
            )
        ),
        FILTER(
            data,
            all_or_crit(1, crit_1) *
                all_or_crit(2, crit_2)
        )
    )
)(A7:B10, B2, B3)



Try using the following formula:


=LET(
     α, A7:B10,
     λ, LAMBDA(δ,ε,ABS(OR((δ ="ALL"),ISBLANK(δ))-(ε=δ))),
     FILTER(α,λ(B2,TAKE(α,,1))*λ(B3,TAKE(α,,-1))))



b3 could be "all" too.
FYI, I also have many many selection options in my report so the simpler the better :-)

@andyleary what all the conditions are.  Is it possible that there will be only ALL for Name: or for Leader only ALL?

Name could be All, a or b.
Leader could be All, 1,2 or 3

@andyleary but never blank right?

yes, it could be blank too. I was thinking of using a wildcard such as ** but that doesn't seem to work with filter function

@andyleary I have an update for you, feel free to test!!
